# Error with pagination while using rpsec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, pagination, railstutorial.org

I' on Micheal Hartl tutorial chapter 9 .And i'm trying to check for if the users name are  displayed on the page . but i'm getting this error

```
Failure/Error: User.paginate.(page:1).each do |user|
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

i probably got to change this part `User.paginate.(page: 1).each do |user|`. but  what do i have to do ?.

here the code inside the rspect directory.

```
describe "index" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before do
        sign_in user 
        30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

    it "should list each user" do
      User.paginate.(page: 1).each do |user|
        page.should have_selector('li>a', text: user.name )
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Do you have the will_paginate gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an extra period after paginate. It should be:

```
    User.paginate(page: 1).each
```